# jQuery: inactivity refresh/logout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below jQuery to refresh my datatable.  I know there is a better way to do this, but for the time being, this is what is working for me:

```
 var idleTime = 0;
 var idleInterval = setInterval(funcion(){
   idleTime = idleTime + 1;
   if (idleTime > 1)
   {
     $('#example1').DataTable().state.clear();
     window.location.reload();
   }
 }, 60000);

 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
   idleTime = 0;
 });
 $(this).keypress(function(e){
   idleTime = 0;
 });
```

Using the above code, after about 1 minute, the page will clear the datatable and reload the page.

Is there something that I can add to the code that will look at how many times it has refreshed due to inactivity?  And then after 120 refreshes, log the user out.

I am not sure if this can be done being that the page keeps refreshing.

Comment: Keep a count in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, depending on the length of time you want to retain the info. However a better solution may be to set the server session timeout to 1 minute and not have to worry about the client

Comment: the use of window.location is not the best way. perhaps is an easy way but you can use ajax something like : $.get('your url') to get data and adding it to the dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to keep track of the number of reloads between reloads. Since you reload the entire page I can quickly think of two ways:

1) use cookies to keep the number and reset the cookie properly if there is activity

2) use parameters to send the value to the server and let the server insert it back into your javascript

That is if you want to handle this in javascript.

Normally you handle a logout in the server side session. Then you have to make sure your auto reload is not identified by the server as "activity".

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I have well like to offer you a simple solution, but as long as you use jquery already better enjoy it with using ajax.

```
 var idleTime = 0;
 var idleInterval = setInterval(funcion(){
   idleTime = idleTime + 1;
   if (idleTime > 1)
   {
     var url      = window.location.href + 'page_table.php'; 
     //you should specify a page_table.php that return only the table.

      $.get(url, function( data ) {
          $('#example1').html(data);    //<----- refresh only the zone with the id : #example
          $('#example1').DataTable();   // <---- important : set the element as DataTable.
      });
   }
 }, 60000);

 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
   idleTime = 0;
 });
 $(this).keypress(function(e){
   idleTime = 0;
 });
```

the idea is to refresh only the part of table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep the current code that you have if it works for you, and let's not depend on localStorage, or additional tricks that might or might not work depending on the browser. Let's store the information in the url.

Like this:

```
var idleTime = 0,
    refreshCount = window.location.hash ?
            Number(window.location.hash.replace("#", '')) : 0; //get current counter
var idleInterval = setInterval(function(){
     //...all your existent code

     /*let's rewrite the url with our new counter, so now when the 
       page is reloaded and th script is executed it gets the new value */
     if(refreshCount == 60) {
        //do your magic it has been refreshed 60 times
     } else {
        window.location = window.location.href.replace('#' + refreshCount, '') 
                        + '#' + (refreshCount+1);
        window.location.reload();
     }
}, 1000);
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.